# Debugger Run's flow correctly but Process Builder only runs flow once

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I have a flow that will successfully send email alerts for any fields that are updated on the record. However, I have run into a bit of an odd bug. I'm calling this flow from a Process Builder.

I have 4 Checkboxes that can kick off the flow and each one should send an email alert. But the logic only works correctly the first time any of the boxes are checked. However, the flow debugger running the record manually will behave correctly.

**Reproduce**

1. Call Flow from Process Builder
2. Update 2/4 checkboxes to TRUE
3. Save Record
4. Process Builder runs as expected and 2 emails are sent.
5. Update the other 2 checkboxes so that now the record has 4/4 emails sent.
6. The result is that the 2 emails that should send on the second update does not kick off the process builder.

**Using Debugger it Works**

1. Hard code Opportunity Id into Flow "Get Record" and deactivate the Process Builder.
2. **Result:** 2 emails sent on update 1, and the second update  2 more emails sent on the second update. (This is the correct behavior of the flow. Every checkbox should send a single email).

**Question**
Why is the debugger behaving correctly, but the Process Builder will only fire on the first update of the opp? [image]

**Process Builder Screens Shot**

Advanced Setting has been set to false. Prior to the conversation here it was marked TRUE. Given that we need to send emails an hour after run time, and have a scenario where multiple emails may need to be sent, there did not appear to be a way to allow a scheduled action to continue to the next criteria. This is what directed us to use a Flow. 
[image: Process Builder with Advanced Setting set to False]

Comment: (A) did you choose the "Trigger this flow only when criteria is met" option? (B) Why not just do this in Process Builder without the flow? You can send emails directly from PB.

Comment: This clearly is problem with process builder. It would help if you can show how you implemented PB in question with screenshots.

Comment: @sfdcfox we already have a process builder that is the email flow for our opportunities, and are trying to keep the email sends within in the same PB. Secondly, we need to delay the send by 60min. You can't continue the PB flow to the next criteria when you use scheduled processes.  I'll post a screen shot of the PB to give more clarity. The checkbox I had to remove was: "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" = FALSE allows the flow to behave as intended.

Comment: New screenshots added.